# Azure: Table acl GET using Azure REST API do not work when done as per documentation

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I am following the Azure REST documentation for [GET ACL Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-acl), [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services#table-service-shared-key-authentication).

Below is the code snippet for REST operation I am performing.

```
//Input your Storage Account and access-key associated to it.
const yourStorageAccountName = '';
const accessKeyStorageAccount = '';
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
const crypto = require("crypto");

async function getTableAcl() {
    let now = new Date();
    let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();
    let contentType = "application/json"
    // construct input value
    let stringToSign = `GET\n\n\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/tablename\ncomp:acl`;
    let accesskey = accessKeyStorageAccount;
    // create base64 encoded signature
    let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
    hmac.update(stringToSign);
    let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
    console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
    console.log("nowutc : " + nowUTC);
    let args = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
            "Date": nowUTC,
            "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11"
        }
    };
    let restClient = new Client();
    restClient.get(`https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/tablename?comp=acl`, args, function (data, response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //console.log(response);
    });
}

getTableAcl()
```

The catch here is that there is no mention of Content-Type in [Azure Table ACL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-acl) but in Authorization header part it is given to include Content-Type. Hence I am keeping the content-type as empty in "stringToSign" and am not providing the Content-Type header in the REST call. I might be missing something but I am not able to determine what it could be.

Can you let me know if I am mising anything in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is that you're generating canonicalized resource string correctly.

The documentation states the following:

> **2009-09-19 and later Shared Key Lite and Table service format**
>
> This format supports Shared Key and Shared Key Lite for all versions
> of the Table service, and Shared Key Lite for version 2009-09-19 and
> later of the Blob and Queue services and version 2014-02-14 and later
> of the File service. This format is identical to that used with
> previous versions of the storage services. Construct the
> CanonicalizedResource string in this format as follows:
>
> 1. Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/), followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>    accessed.
> 2. Append the resource's encoded URI path. If the request URI addresses a component of the resource, append the appropriate query
>    string. The query string should include the question mark and the comp
>    parameter (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be
>    included on the query string.

Based on this, your `stringToSign` should be:

```
let stringToSign = `GET\n\n\n${nowUTC}\n/${yourStorageAccountName}/tablename?comp=acl`;
```

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me.