# Cannot authorize query to Azure Table Service

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage

I am trying to set up an API to get information from Azure Table Storage. I've been following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) and a similar issue on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397953/azure-table-acl-get-using-azure-rest-api-do-not-work-when-done-as-per-documenta), but I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm getting an HTTP 403 error *"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."*. Here is the code. For now I'm just trying to do a basic query to the /Tables resource to get going, though eventually I'm going to be querying specific rowIDs.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const yourStorageAccountName = 'XXXXXXXX';

let CanonicalizedResource = `${yourStorageAccountName}/Tables`;
let url = `https://${yourStorageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/Tables`;

let now = new Date();
let nowUTC = now.toUTCString();

let stringToSign = `GET\n\n\n${nowUTC}\n${CanonicalizedResource}`;
let accesskey = `YYYYYYYY`;
let key = new Buffer(accesskey, "base64");
let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key);
hmac.update(stringToSign);
let sig = hmac.digest("base64");
console.log("SIGNATURE : " + sig);
console.log("nowutc : " + nowUTC);
let headers = {
        "Authorization": "SharedKey " + yourStorageAccountName + ":" + sig,
        "x-ms-date": nowUTC,
        "Date": nowUTC,
        "x-ms-version": "2015-12-11"
};

var response = request({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
});

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following code to create share key

```
const accesskey=""
    const storageAccount = ""
    const resource = "Tables"

    const data =  new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    const GMTTime = data.toUTCString()
    console.log(GMTTime)

    //Shared Key authorization
    const StringToSign= "GET"+"\n"
                           +"\n"
                           +"\n"
                           + GMTTime +"\n"
                           +"/"+ storageAccount+"/"+resource

    const Sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(accesskey, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf8').digest('base64');
    console.log(Sig)

    //Shared Key Lite authorization
    const stringToSign = GMTTime +"\n"+"/"+ storageAccount+"/"+resource
    const sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(accesskey, 'base64')).update(stringToSign, 'utf8').digest('base64');
    console.log(sig)
```

[image]

Test(Q[uery tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables))
1. Shared Key authorization

```
GET https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Tables
Headers
       Authorization : SharedKey <account name>:kHl5K0AzsG7M32***AoxmCFY=
       x-ms-date : <the data you use to create share key>
       Accept : application/json;odata=nometadata
       x-ms-version : 2017-04-17
```

[image]

2. Shared Key Lite authorization

```
GET https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Tables
Headers
       Authorization : SharedKeyLite <account name>:0fADhBTi7tvtm***h69Y433c=
       x-ms-date : <the data you use to create share key>
       Accept : application/json;odata=nometadata
       x-ms-version : 2017-04-17
```

[image]

Besides, if you want to use Azure Table nodejs sdk `azure-storage`, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs) and the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#table-storage)

1. install sdk

```
npm install azure-storage
```

2. Code

```
var azure=require('azure-storage')
async function main() {
    const accesskey=""
    const storageAccount = ""
    var tableService=azure.createTableService(storageAccount,accesskey);
    tableService.listTablesSegmented(null,function(error,result){

        if(error){
           console.log(error)

        }else{

            for (var i = 0, table; table = result.entries[i]; i++) {
                console.log(table)
            }

        }

    })
  }

  // An async method returns a Promise object, which is compatible with then().catch() coding style.
  main()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Successfully executed the sample.");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: This worked. I was actually able to use my original sample but there were two errors in my code that caused it to fail. 1) I was missing the leading slash in the CanonicalizedResource and 2) the `Accept : application/json;odata=nometadata` line in the header seems to be required. I got my sample to work as well once I made those changes. Thanks for your help!